# Issues with various https sites using Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, ssl, debian

Since last few months I am having SSL certification and timeout issues on various sites.
Someone explained well here [e.g](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/problems-browsing-secure-sites-https-673274/). The solution suggested is to regenerate ssl certificates but I dont know how to do that stuff. Could some one help sort out that.

```
lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)
Release:    7.6

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013


dpkg -l | grep openssl
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64                      2.12.20-8+deb7u2                   amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  openssl                                        1.0.1e-2+deb7u11                   amd64  

  Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
```

Comment: I think the person who answered in that Linux forum was talking about the router (i.e., *"your installation"*) in the answer. I don't believe that's correct. Debian weak keys could allow someone to decrypt the traffic. It should not effect QoS. Can you swap out you Access Point for another? Can you switch channels? Something like: [How to boost your WiFi speed by choosing the right channel](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/179344-how-to-boost-your-wifi-speed-by-choosing-the-right-channel).

Comment: *If* this is not a Wifi issue, then try a new hub or switch; and try a new network cable. If they don't fix it, then try a new network card on your Linux box.

Comment: Are u suggesting this as hardware issue ?